# Is there a reliable source for the strapline of The Sabrina the Teenage Witch Show being what Wikipedia reports?

Tags: production, the-sabrina-the-teenage-witch-show

Wikipedia reports that the strapline of [The Sabrina the Teenage Witch Show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabrina_the_Teenage_Witch_(1970_TV_series)) is:

> Once upon a time, there were three witches, who lived in the little town of Riverdale. Two aunts, Hilda and Zelda, are choosing the ingredients to create an evil wicked witch. But suddenly, Zelda bumped right into Hilda and accidentally added beautiful girls' stuff as an extra ingredient.

This sounded so peculiarly similar to the Powerpuff Girls / Whoopass Girls's creation story of an accidental mixing of Chemical X into the ingredients for a perfect little girl, that I don't believe it.

Does anyone have a source for this strapline? Wikipedia's citations don't list one for that section of the page.

Comment: ["The series' opening narration"](https://archiecomics.fandom.com/wiki/The_Sabrina_the_Teenage_Witch_Show)

Comment: @BCdotWEB - Oh, right, I forgot that page. ... But I've seen first few minutes of the first episode on YouTube, and the opening, https://youtu.be/YvTUN5KsDAM ... And none of those have that narration?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to be supported by the actual episodes as they can be found online.